# Bluetooth audio on Android TV disconnects after 30s from any Kubuntu PC

Tags: sound, kubuntu, bluetooth, kde, android

I don't know where to post this (Android forum? KDE forum?). I've been researching this issue for hours with not a hint of a solution.

I have a brand new Xgimi projector with Android TV on it. The sound is good, so I want to use it as audio over bluetooth for various devices.

It works fine from any Android phone or tablet.

But from 3 different Kubuntu PCs (1yo, 11yo and 3yo, all up to date 23.10), the audio disconnects after 30s (Bluetooth stays connected though). The same PCs have to problem connecting to various BT headphones I've tested.

So the problem is purely from KDE/Linux to Android TV. When starting music over BT, the projector starts an app (?) called XMusic player. After 30s the profile disappears from the PulseAudio volume control while the BT connection is still present (on both ends).

dmesg doesn't show anything besides `input: gjs projo (AVRCP) as /devices/virtual/input/input58` upon connection.

`/var/log/syslog` has the following (simplified):

```
# Bluetooth connection established
bluetoothd[1276]: src/service.c:btd_service_connect() a2dp-source profile connect failed for DC:97:58:78:6D:54: Device or resource busy
bluetoothd[1276]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_DC_97_58_78_6D_54/sep2/fd5: fd(42) ready
kernel: [3348060.664812] input: gjs projo (AVRCP) as /devices/virtual/input/input51

# Start playing music manually over BT
wireplumber[3749]: 0x5591ad87f678: error 24
wireplumber[3749]: (bluez_output.DC_97_58_78_6D_54.1-87) running -> error (Received error event)
wireplumber[3749]: Failure in Bluetooth audio transport /org/bluez/hci0/dev_DC_97_58_78_6D_54/sep2/fd5
pipewire[3746]: pw.node: (bluez_output.DC_97_58_78_6D_54.1-87) running -> error (Received error event)
org.kde.kdeconnect[4434]: org.kde.pulseaudio: No object for name "bluez_output.DC_97_58_78_6D_54.1"
plasmashell[4125]: org.kde.plasma.pulseaudio: No object for name "bluez_output.DC_97_58_78_6D_54.1"
pipewire[3746]: spa.audioadapter: 0x55fcd52e3da8: scheduling stopped node

# Music fails over BT after 30s
plasmashell[4125]: QQmlExpression: Expression file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.private.systemtray/contents/ui/ExpandedRepresentation.qml:181:21 depends on non-NOTIFYable properties:
plasmashell[4125]:     QAction::priority
plasmashell[4125]: message repeated 2 times: [     QAction::priority]
plasmashell[4125]: QQmlExpression: Expression file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.private.systemtray/contents/ui/ExpandedRepresentation.qml:82:17 depends on non-NOTIFYable properties:
plasmashell[4125]:     QAction::priority
plasmashell[4125]: message repeated 2 times: [     QAction::priority]
kwin_x11[4061]: kwin_core: XCB error: 152 (BadDamage), sequence: 1490, resource id: 30723735, major code: 143 (DAMAGE), minor code: 3 (Subtract)

# Manual BT disconnect (no messages)
```

Also while connected:

```
$ inxi -Alsa -j
Audio:
Device-1: Intel Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Audio vendor: Dell
    driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel alternate: snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl
    bus-ID: 00:1f.3 chip-ID: 8086:a0c8 class-ID: 0403
API: ALSA v: k6.5.0-17-generic status: kernel-api
    tools: alsactl,alsamixer,amixer
Server-1: PipeWire v: 0.3.79 status: active with: 1: pipewire-pulse
    status: active 2: wireplumber status: active tools: pw-cat,pw-cli,wpctl
Server-2: PulseAudio v: 16.1 status: off (using pipewire-pulse)
    tools: pacat,pactl,pavucontrol
Swap:
Kernel: swappiness: 60 (default) cache-pressure: 100 (default) zswap: no
ID-1: swap-1 type: partition size: 15.95 GiB used: 8.39 GiB (52.6%)
    priority: -2 dev: /dev/dm-2 maj-min: 252:2 mapped: vgkubuntu-swap_1
    label: N/A
Sensors:
Src: /sys System Temperatures: cpu: 46.0 C mobo: N/A
Fan Speeds (rpm): N/A
Power: 12v: N/A 5v: 5 3.3v: N/A vbat: N/A

$ systemctl --user status pipewire pipewire-pulse wireplumber | cat
● pipewire.service - PipeWire Multimedia Service
    Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pipewire.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
    Active: active (running) since Sun 2024-02-18 15:25:45 CET; 1 month 8 days ago
TriggeredBy: ● pipewire.socket
Main PID: 3746 (pipewire)
    Tasks: 3 (limit: 18723)
    Memory: 16.1M
        CPU: 38min 56.709s
    CGroup: /user.slice/user-10705.slice/user@10705.service/session.slice/pipewire.service
            └─3746 /usr/bin/pipewire

Mar 25 10:11:26 lpsc0175x pipewire[3746]: spa.audioadapter: 0x55fcd52e3da8: scheduling stopped node
Mar 25 16:26:14 lpsc0175x pipewire[3746]: spa.audioadapter: 0x55fcd52e3da8: scheduling stopped node
Mar 27 15:46:39 lpsc0175x pipewire[3746]: spa.audioadapter: 0x55fcd52e3da8: scheduling stopped node
Mar 28 09:21:17 lpsc0175x pipewire[3746]: pw.node: (bluez_output.DC_97_58_78_6D_54.1-70) running -> error (Received error event)
Mar 28 09:22:22 lpsc0175x pipewire[3746]: pw.node: (bluez_output.DC_97_58_78_6D_54.1-41) running -> error (Received error event)
Mar 28 09:25:53 lpsc0175x pipewire[3746]: pw.node: (bluez_output.DC_97_58_78_6D_54.1-87) running -> error (Received error event)
Mar 28 09:25:53 lpsc0175x pipewire[3746]: spa.audioadapter: 0x55fcd52e3da8: scheduling stopped node
Mar 28 09:35:32 lpsc0175x pipewire[3746]: pw.node: (bluez_output.DC_97_58_78_6D_54.1-41) running -> error (Received error event)
Mar 28 10:05:29 lpsc0175x pipewire[3746]: pw.node: (bluez_output.DC_97_58_78_6D_54.1-67) running -> error (Received error event)
Mar 28 10:06:27 lpsc0175x pipewire[3746]: pw.node: (bluez_output.DC_97_58_78_6D_54.1-73) running -> error (Received error event)

● pipewire-pulse.service - PipeWire PulseAudio
    Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pipewire-pulse.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
    Active: active (running) since Sun 2024-02-18 15:25:45 CET; 1 month 8 days ago
TriggeredBy: ● pipewire-pulse.socket
Main PID: 3755 (pipewire-pulse)
    Tasks: 3 (limit: 18723)
    Memory: 38.9M
        CPU: 33min 6.067s
    CGroup: /user.slice/user-10705.slice/user@10705.service/session.slice/pipewire-pulse.service
            └─3755 /usr/bin/pipewire-pulse

Feb 18 15:25:45 lpsc0175x systemd[3736]: Started pipewire-pulse.service - PipeWire PulseAudio.
Mar 28 10:31:51 lpsc0175x pipewire-pulse[3755]: mod.protocol-pulse: client 0x55ede1df7aa0 [PulseAudio Volume Control]: ERROR command:104 (SEND_OBJECT_MESSAGE) tag:38 error:3 (Invalid argument)
Mar 28 10:31:51 lpsc0175x pipewire-pulse[3755]: mod.protocol-pulse: client 0x55ede1df7aa0 [PulseAudio Volume Control]: ERROR command:104 (SEND_OBJECT_MESSAGE) tag:39 error:3 (Invalid argument)

● wireplumber.service - Multimedia Service Session Manager
    Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/wireplumber.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
    Active: active (running) since Sun 2024-02-18 15:25:45 CET; 1 month 8 days ago
Main PID: 3749 (wireplumber)
    Tasks: 6 (limit: 18723)
    Memory: 9.9M
        CPU: 38.459s
    CGroup: /user.slice/user-10705.slice/user@10705.service/session.slice/wireplumber.service
            └─3749 /usr/bin/wireplumber

Mar 28 09:35:32 lpsc0175x wireplumber[3749]: (bluez_output.DC_97_58_78_6D_54.1-41) running -> error (Received error event)
Mar 28 09:35:32 lpsc0175x wireplumber[3749]: Failure in Bluetooth audio transport /org/bluez/hci0/dev_DC_97_58_78_6D_54/sep2/fd7
Mar 28 09:48:36 lpsc0175x wireplumber[3749]: 0x5591ad87f678: error 24
Mar 28 09:48:36 lpsc0175x wireplumber[3749]: Failed to release transport /org/bluez/hci0/dev_FC_58_FA_C6_BB_3B/sep1/fd8: Method "Release" with signature "" on interface "org.bluez.MediaTransport1" doesn't exist
Mar 28 10:05:29 lpsc0175x wireplumber[3749]: 0x5591ad87f678: error 24
Mar 28 10:05:29 lpsc0175x wireplumber[3749]: (bluez_output.DC_97_58_78_6D_54.1-67) running -> error (Received error event)
Mar 28 10:05:29 lpsc0175x wireplumber[3749]: Failure in Bluetooth audio transport /org/bluez/hci0/dev_DC_97_58_78_6D_54/sep2/fd10
Mar 28 10:06:27 lpsc0175x wireplumber[3749]: 0x5591ad87f678: error 24
Mar 28 10:06:27 lpsc0175x wireplumber[3749]: (bluez_output.DC_97_58_78_6D_54.1-73) running -> error (Received error event)
Mar 28 10:06:27 lpsc0175x wireplumber[3749]: Failure in Bluetooth audio transport /org/bluez/hci0/dev_DC_97_58_78_6D_54/sep2/fd11
```

I've deleted `~/.local/state/wireplumber`, no change.
On one PC I've set `session.suspend-timeout-seconds` to 0 in `/etc/wireplumber/main.lua.d/50-alsa-config.lua`, but the other one doesn't have a `/etc/wireplumber` directory.

I don't know what else I can do.